# Get only first result in subquery for each row order by custom column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

my brain can't resolve a simple (i think) SQL problem and i need your help. I searched a lot of Stackoverflow but can't find the right answer for my case.

What i have :

table : expense_budgets
id
per_member
maximum
from_date
organization_id
organization_type_id
created_at
updated_at

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `expense_budgets` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `per_member` double NOT NULL,
  `maximum` double NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `organization_type_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

```sql
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 10, 10000, NULL, NULL, 2, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (2, 5, 5000, NULL, NULL, 3, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, 10, 40, NULL, NULL, 4, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (4, 5, 5000, NULL, NULL, 5, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (6, 15, 15000, '2020-09-25', NULL, 2, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (7, 15, 15000, '2020-09-29', NULL, 2, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (8, 15, 15000, '2020-09-26', NULL, 2, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
INSERT INTO `expense_budgets` (`id`, `per_member`, `maximum`, `from_date`, `organization_id`, `organization_type_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (9, 15, 15000, '2020-09-27', NULL, 2, '2020-09-14 16:43:52', NULL);
```

What i want : I have to get the closest expense_budget record for each of my organization types for a given date. So i apply a weight custom column to order them. If i have only one record with a null `from_date` that means that is the default value, if i have a date i want the closest lower from_date from now.

```sql
SELECT id, organization_type_id, case when from_date IS null then 1 when CURDATE() >= from_date THEN 3 ELSE 2 END AS weight
FROM expense_budgets
ORDER BY weight desc,from_date ASC;
```

But i can't find out how to integrate this in a subquery or a join to get a result to get this (if the current date is 2020-09-28) :

```
id;per_member;maximum;from_date;organization_id;organization_type_id;created_at;updated_at
2;5;5000;NULL;NULL;3;2020-09-14 16:43:52;NULL
3;10;40;NULL;NULL;4;2020-09-14 16:43:52;NULL
4;5;5000;NULL;NULL;5;2020-09-14 16:43:52;2020-09-28 09:46:24
9;15;15000;2020-09-27;NULL;2;2020-09-14 16:43:52;NULL
```

You got it ? only one record for each organization_type_id with the selected value based on the order made fron the case subquery.

In advance, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the combination organization_type_id + from_date is unique:

```
with lastbudgets as (select eb2.organization_type_id, max(eb2.from_date) as from_date
                       from expense_budgets eb2
                      where eb2.from_date is null or eb2.from_date <= now()
                      group by eb2.organization_type_id)
select eb.* 
  from expense_budgets eb 
     inner join lastbudgets lb 
             on lb.organization_type_id = eb.organization_type_id
            and ((lb.from_date is null and eb.from_date is null) or lb.from_date = eb.from_date)
```

UPDATED: extra logic on null case

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this query gives me only one result because the column `from_date` can be null for a default value.
And i think the MAX function is not the correct way because a max of `from_date` is not always the correct choice, i can have future date so not yet applicable today.

Comment: I've modified the query. I don't have mysql db available. I assume max() returns non-null value if at least one date is not null.

Comment: It's seems to work perfectly and it resolved my problem. You'r the best !

Answer (score 0):

You could try to edit your question by adding sample data in this format below:

- put in a line containing ```` ```SQL ````, that's three back-ticks followed by the keyword SQL.
- then put in your data in the format I put in below (I ignored create/change timestamp, as they seem irrelevant to the problem). I'm only sure the data is not representative, so you'll have to tweak it to reflect your challenge.
- End your "quoted code" input with a line, only containing: ```` ``` ````

````
```SQL
WITH
expense_budgets(id,per_member,maximum,fromdt,orgid,org_tpid) AS (
          SELECT  1,15,15000,DATE '2020-09-12',NULL::INT,2
UNION ALL SELECT  2,20,15000,DATE '2020-09-13',NULL::INT,3
UNION ALL SELECT  3, 5,15000,DATE '2020-09-14',NULL::INT,4
UNION ALL SELECT  4,35,15000,DATE '2020-09-15',NULL::INT,2
UNION ALL SELECT  5, 5,15000,DATE '2020-09-16',NULL::INT,3
UNION ALL SELECT  6,15,15000,DATE '2020-09-17',NULL::INT,4
UNION ALL SELECT  7, 2,15000,DATE '2020-09-18',NULL::INT,2
UNION ALL SELECT  8, 7,15000,DATE '2020-09-19',NULL::INT,3
UNION ALL SELECT  9, 6,15000,DATE '2020-09-20',NULL::INT,4
UNION ALL SELECT 10, 5,15000,DATE '2020-09-21',NULL::INT,2
UNION ALL SELECT 11,35,15000,DATE '2020-09-22',NULL::INT,3
UNION ALL SELECT 12,15,15000,DATE '2020-09-23',NULL::INT,4
)
SELECT * FROM expense_budgets ; -- < replace with real query, please ...
-- ``` un-comment this , (three back-ticks don't display in quoted code ...
````